# How can I direct apt-get to download package and its dependencies to some other location?

Tags: installation, package-management, apt

How can I direct `apt-get install package_name` to download package and its dependencies to some other location instead of `/var/cache/apt/archives`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can download a package and all its dependencies with the following command, provided neither the package nor its dependencies are installed in the machine:

```
sudo apt-get --download-only -o Dir::Cache="/path/to/destination/dir/" \
    -o Dir::Cache::archives="./" install package_name
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try:

```
cd /directory
apt-get download package_name*
```

Comment: note that this will work for distros >= raring

Answer (score 3):

You can edit file `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and add this:

```
Dir::Cache::Archives "/path/you/want/";
```

Note that from now on, all downloaded files by apt will be stored on that dir.
To disable it, you only need to comment that line (with `#`)