# Apt-get upgrade / dist-upgrade, but with minimal steps (one package at a time); apt download dir?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

My server is pretty tight on disk space (on the system partition; data is kept on a separate, pretty large disk).

It can install everything — but not while also having a bunch of packages downloaded, waiting to install, using up space. As a result, because `apt-get upgrade` normally downloads everything first and then installs, the installs keep failing on `No space left on device`.

So is there a simple way for me too tell `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` to

1. Do one package at a time (like `unattended-upgrades`' `minimum-steps` option), and/or
2. Put the downloaded waiting-install packages (and for that matter, the full `apt-get update` sources files) to a separate disk?

(Yes, I could write a script myself to list all the upgradeable packages and then iterate. I'm wondering if this already A Thing somehow, since it seems like it ought to be, but I've not been able to find it.)

ETA:

#2 was [answered](https://askubuntu.com/a/80693/1124679) by [Salem](https://askubuntu.com/users/33871/salem):

You can edit file `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and add this:

```
Dir::Cache::Archives "/path/you/want/";
```

Note that from now on, all downloaded files by apt will be stored on that dir.
To disable it, you only need to comment that line (with `#`)